# Only select rows where seqnum is a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following script, how do I only include rows where seqnum =1. Currently everything is showing up and I only would like rows where [LongName] is unique. I cannot put the WHERE clause around seqnum, it won't recognize the column.

```
SELECT [LongName]
     , [InstanceId]
     , [Number]   
     , [Value]
     , [Employee]
     , [Time]
     , DENSE_RANK() over (partition by [LongName] order by [Time] desc) as seqnum 
FROM [DataValue]
INNER JOIN [NumberPlate] ON DataValueId = NumberPlate.Id
WHERE [Number] LIKE '%55AA0%' AND [Employee]=1 
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

what my query does

```
InstanceID  Number  Value       LongName    Employee    Time    seqnum
40            1      5105.993   Parameter C    1    05:10.0   1
20            1      5117.298   Parameter D    1    05:10.0   1
12            1      5126.925   Parameter E    0    05:10.0   1
46            1      5132.83    Parameter B    4    05:10.0   1
453           1      GG2        Parameter A    0    05:10.0   1
345           1      55D        Parameter B    0    05:09.9   2
234           1      5287.562   Parameter D    1    05:09.9   2
865           1      5310.893   Parameter C    2    05:09.9   2
23            1      5105.993   Parameter B    2    05:09.9   2
245           1      GG3        Parameter A    3    03:57.8   2
```

what i would like

```
InstanceID  Number  Value       LongName    Employee    Time    seqnum
40            1      5105.993   Parameter C    1    05:10.0   1
20            1      5117.298   Parameter D    1    05:10.0   1
12            1      5126.925   Parameter E    0    05:10.0   1
46            1      5132.83    Parameter B    4    05:10.0   1
453           1      GG2        Parameter A    0    05:10.0   1
```

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and qualify your column names so others people understand what the query is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a CTE as below:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [LongName]
      ,[InstanceId]
      ,[Number]   
      ,[Value]
      ,[Employee]
      ,[Time]
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [LongName] ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS seqnum
FROM 
   [DataValue]
    INNER JOIN [NumberPlate] ON DataValueId = NumberPlate.Id
WHERE
    [Number] LIKE '%55AA0%' AND [Employee]=1 
)
SELECT *
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    seqnum = 1 
ORDER BY 
    [Time] 
DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

A fun way to do this uses `SELECT WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [LongName], [InstanceId], [Number]   , [Value], [Employee], [Time]
FROM [DataValue] INNER JOIN
     [NumberPlate]
     ON DataValueId = NumberPlate.Id
WHERE [Number] LIKE '%55AA0%' AND [Employee]=1 
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() over (partition by [LongName] order by [Time] desc) as seqnum ;
```

If you really want the final results ordered by `time`, though, you need an additional subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Just your query in the sub-query:

```
Select * from 
(SELECT [LongName]
      ,[InstanceId]
      ,[Number]   
      ,[Value]
      ,[Employee]
      ,[Time]
       ,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by [LongName] order by [Time] desc) as seqnum 
  
  FROM [DataValue]
  INNER JOIN [NumberPlate]
  On DataValueId = NumberPlate.Id
  
 WHERE [Number] LIKE '%55AA0%' AND [Employee]=1 
  ORDER BY [Time] DESC)
where seqnum = 1;
```